# setattr does not respect attributes naming conventions

Tags: python-3.x, attributes, naming-conventions, setattr

I had a weird encounter the other day, where the following code:

```
class Obj:
    pass
obj = Obj()
setattr(obj, '@#^&%$&', None)
```

actually worked. Why is this behavior allowed, if the following raises syntaxerror ? :
`obj.@#^&%$&`

Comment: It works because its roughly equivalent to writing: `obj.__dict__['@#^&%$&'] = None`. But that doesn't make it right ;)

Answer (score 0):

All the `setattr` function does is to assign to the object's `__dict__` dictionary the given value at the given key. It does not do any validation against the key, so you can retrieve the value with `getattr` like this:

```
getattr(obj, '@#^&%$&')
```

which returns the value you assigned to the said key:

```
None
```

The attribute name after the dot notation, however, is not part of a quoted string, and therefore does have to follow the Python naming syntax or the interpreter cannot parse it properly.